# SPOOL compiler out when executing function creation script in SQL*PLUS

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm having an issue to obtain compiler error from preProd server when executing and script to create a function.
Script is executed using SQL*Plus but we don't see any detail about compiler output.

We use SPOOL like with a select, update, etc query but now no details about error are written in spool file.
We obtain *Function created with compilation errors* everytime but we don't know what are the errors to solve them.

Instead in DEV using Oracle SQL Developer we obtain details.

What do we need to configure to obtain compilator out in an output file.

[image: Compilator details in Oracle SQL Dev]

Comment: Please [edit] the question to include a [MRE] with: a **complete** example of a script that generates the output you are seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would probably help us help you if you posted **script** you're executing from SQL*Plus.

Output which is **similar** to yours: first, I'm creating a procedure which fails as table doesn't exist:

```
SQL> create or replace procedure p_test is
  2    l_cnt number;
  3  begin
  4    select count(*)
  5      into l_cnt
  6      from table_that_does_not_exist;
  7  end;
  8  /

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

SQL> show err
Errors for PROCEDURE P_TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
6/10     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
SQL>
```

Then, I'm executing `test.sql` script which creates a function, shows errors and terminates spool. This is the script:

```
set feedback on
create or replace function f_test return number is
begin
  return 1;
end;
/
show err procedure p_test
spool off
```

When I call it from SQL*Plus:

```
SQL> @test

Function created.

Errors for PROCEDURE P_TEST:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
4/3      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
6/10     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
not spooling currently
SQL>
```

So:

- function is created
- error stack is displayed (**not** related to function, but procedure that selects from table that doesn't exist)
- `spool off` fails because I'm NOT spooling currently

  - if you were spooling, maybe you'd see something in output file. But, as you aren't spooling, there's no file (or - maybe there's an old file, created *two days ago*) and no info you're looking for

---

As I said: this is *similar* to what you have. If possible, post everything you did (hide irrelevant or sensitive parts) so that we'd see some more info.

Comment: Function or procedure it's easy. But i'm going to try show err command. I didn't know it.

Comment: Problem solved. Finally ploted the error and found that the problem is related to line ending. I'm editing the script in Windows but executing in UNIX machines.

Comment: Aha. OK, thank you for letting us know, I'm glad you fixed it.